# How to hide published application from app listings in the Play store and app store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Android and ios apps are being developed to share company low-risk information with all the employees (5000 users).

When it comes to app distribution we are in a problem with sharing the app due to the following.

1. Hide from the google play store app listing since this app is required for employees within the organization only without unpublishing the app.
2. Expected Distribution: We are planning to share a play store and app store link with users to download the mobile app.
3. Cannot share APK with the employees since they are not that tech-savvy to manage such requests.
4. End-User details: Some do have office-provided email id with access from external devices and others do not. Users have android, ios operating systems. Some employees do not have office email id which cannot be accessed through mobile phone
5. Managing End-user application: Admin does not require to manage the application since it is optional for all users to use the application. Since managed Google Play or IOS enterprise are not required and control who can download and monitor devices.

Checked the option of the private app but we do not prefer the following.

1. APK base app distribution (Their phones will have to be set to allow installations from outside the store)
2. Not required to be responsible for limiting access to the app (Since the user creation option is not there for others to login to the app)
3. Hide from making it visible in the play store. We need to limit the public availability not to completely hide the app from the app store or play store (Link 1: Apps can't be published as a private app and in the public Google Play store at the same time.).

Need support on publishing public app and hide from listing them in play store and app store.
Studied on managing private app and publishing
[Manage private Android apps in Google Play](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanaging-private-apps-in-admin-console-versus-google-play-console%2Cimportant-information-about-app-publishing)

Comment: You can't hide an app in the iOS App Store. If it is published it is visible.

Comment: It sounds like a web app might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**The best option**

With this number of employees you should be eligible to the [Apple Enterprise Account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) which allows you to sign iOS Applications for Distribution (so plugged  to Apple production services) and distribute it without going through the App Store.

You can then distribute both you iOS App and Android apps through a 3rd party system like AppCenter.ms

The only drawbacks:

- the certificate lasts 2 years so you need to update your app before it expires
- User need to accept apps signed from your company https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204460

**Alternative**

Mandatory if you have less than 100 employees.

- You can Apple Business Account https://business.apple.com/
- When publishing the App  on the App Store you can restrict it's visibility for members of this company

Drawbacks:

- You have to manage all you users in Apple Business Account, which is painful (and might require and MDM - never did it)
- You can bypass this by generating Redeem Codes the user can use (once) in the App Store: a little bit easier to manage but still you have to keep track of codes you already shared or not

For Android the AppCenter solution remains otherwise you have to  add everyone in a Google Group for private access

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answer only applies to the iOS side since I do not have experience with Android.

I think that Apple Enterprise Account should be a good fit for you since your company has more that 100 employees. We have been using it for a few years and it is great. The only caveat is that users need to accept apps for your company, but I think you can do that for your users if you are using a MDM solution.

But there is now (since a while back) another alternative to this problem: Unlisted app distribution

https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/

It makes it possible to publish your app on the App Store, but the only way to find the app is by a direct link.

And an important difference of this to Apple Business Manager is that you can distribute the app to both managed and unmanaged devices which makes it possible to let users buy there own devices.

I think that Unlisted app distribution is pretty new but will become more and more common when Apple now (2022) do not let companies with less than 100 employees renew their Apple Enterprise Developer Programs and force those companies to other distribution models.